# Integral Controller design

Tags: power, control, control-system, pid-controller, laplace-transform

For this system, what method do I use to select a value of Ki? Gh and Gt are first-order blocks with time constants Th and Tt- [image]

Comment: Intergal? Between lassies? Or should the title read *integral*?

Answer (score 0):

> *For this system, what method do I use to select a value of Ki?*

This block can be made from an op-amp inverting integrator: -

[image]

For the integrator, if R = 1 and C = 1 then \$K_i\$ would also be one: -

[image]

Hence, you choose values for R and C to give you the value of \$K_i\$ that you require.

Image from [here](https://dwma4bz18k1bd.cloudfront.net/tutorials/op-amp-integrator-tutorial-thumbnail.jpeg)

Comment: What I meant was what method do I use to select a value of Ki, I can't draw a Root Locus because it doesn't simplify to the required algebraic form, if you'd do it via a frequency response method, how do I approach that?

Comment: It depends on the requirements you have to meet (step response in the time domain and/or stability requirements/phase margin in the frequency domain). Start with a Bode diagram for the loop gain (stability check for various Ki values)